# Representable cohomology theories in motivic homotopy theory

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, sheaf-cohomology

I am reading Mazza, Voevodskys and Weibels book on *Lecture Notes on Motivic Cohomology* and have grown curious about the following question:

**Which cohomology theories on $Sm/k$ is representable, i.e. appear as Hom-groups, in Voevodsky's construction of $DM_{\text{Nis}}^{eff,-}(k, R)$?**

If we let $X$ be a scheme of finite type over $k$ and $R$ a commutative unital ring, then we have (by construction) motivic homology with coefficients in $R$
$$H_{n,i}(X, R) = \text{Hom}_{DM_{\text{Nis}}^{eff,-}}(R(i)[n], R_{\text{tr}}(X)),$$
and motivic cohomology
$$H^{n,i}(X, R) = \text{Hom}_{DM_{\text{Nis}}^{eff,-}}(R_{\text{tr}}(X), R(i)[n]).$$
From this, we obtain the algebraic singular homology (and hence Suslin's singular homology) as
$$H^{\text{sing}}_n(X,R) \cong H_{n,0}(X,R)$$
and, if $X$ is a smooth seperated scheme of finite type over some perfect field $k$, the higher Chow groups
$$CH^q(X, 2q-p) = H^{p,q}(X,\mathbb{Z}).$$

It is clear to me that such cohomology theories must satisty certain properties:

- Mayer-Vietories
- $\mathbb{A}^1$-invarience
- Künneth-theorem
- ...

But do we have any other examples of cohomology theories that appear as Hom-groups in $DM_{\text{Nis}}^{eff,-}(k, R)$? How about

- Betti cohomology?
- $l$-adic cohomology?
- Crystalline cohomology?
- Algebraic de Rham cohomology?

Another way of framing the question is: How far off is Voevodsky's-Morel's $DM_{\text{Nis}}^{eff,-}(k, R)$ construction from being the category of pure/mixed motives in the sense of Grothendieck.

(I realize this might be a very hard question to which not much is known.)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  I would recommend asking this on MathOverflow too--you're more likely to get a good answer to research-level questions there.

Comment: @Ravi Thanks! I will do that. I realize that this question may be more suited on MathOverflow.

Comment: Isn't it just Brown representability theorem ? For example with the Betti realization, consider that the realization functor $DM_{Nis}^{eff,-}(k;R)\to D(Ab)$ is triangulated and preserve infinite direct sum, so it has a right adjoint $U$. Then $U(\mathbb{Z})$ represent Betti cohomology. Of course $U(\mathbb{Z})$ is far from being a geometric object in $DM$.

Comment: I don't see the connection with your second question though. $DM$ is supposed to be the derived category of mixed motives (at least its subcategory of compact objects should be the subcategory of compact objects of the derived category of mixed motives). $DM$ certainly is not the category of mixed motives (much less the pure ones).